# Why should you include more than one value in a return statement?

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value

I've seen instances where someone would use return statements with multiple values.  For example: `return 8, 10, 6;`  As far as I know, only one of these values will actually be returned.  What is the benefit of using `return` this way?

Specifically, this question appears on my homework.

> The statement: `return 2 * 3 + 1, 1 + 5;` returns the value ____.

I know it would always return 6, so why would I ever write it like this?

Forgive me if this is a simple question.  I am still somewhat new to programming.

Comment: There is no benefit and this line is equivalent to `return 6;`. Either someone doesn't understand what comma operator does in C++ or they wanted to make fun of future readers of the code.

Comment: .... or you misquote the code. Are you really sure that it was `return 8,10,6;` ? Asking, because eg `return { 8,10,6};` is something completely different.

Comment: Or the coder(s) you refer to are maybe being deliberately obscure. If `status` is a *global* variable, something like `return (status=true), 3;` would have consequences.

Comment: We need to see the real code to tell you why they are doing it that way.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm sure it is `return 8, 10, 6;`.  It always returns 6.

Comment: `I've seen certain C++ functions` Which functions? What did they do? Where did you see them? Can you post those functions? Can you provide sources to these functions so others can inspect them?

Comment: thats a trick quesiton, not real code

Comment: @idclev463035818 Oh ok.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: so actually you didnt see any function with such a return statement, right? Context matters. A lot.

Comment: My bad.  I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `return 2 * 3 + 1, 1 + 5;` returns the value **6**.

This the trick of **comma operator** in C++. You can read more about it here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

A **comma operator** is basically a list of expressions separated by commas, they will be evaluated from left to right, and the result of the last item will be treated as the result of the whole **comma operator**.

Here is a simple example demonstrating how **comma operator** works.

```
int foo() {
    int i = 1;
    return i += 2, i++, i + 5; // This is a comma operator with three items
                               // i += 2 will be evaluated first, then i == 3
                               // i++ will be evaluated second, then i == 4
                               // i + 5 will be evaluate last, and the result is 9
                               // the result of the last item is returned by the return statement
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints 9.

Answer (score -1):

When you do this you are avoiding using math in your function block and this make your function like working 3 time and result would be the one you want